# Extracting arguments from input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, command-line-arguments

I wonder if there is some neat way to extract user input arguments from the `input()` function and store them in a `list`. Exactly like `sys.argv` stores the command line arguments.

So for example, if the user inputs

> square 4 "string with space" -arg

The `list` of args should contain `['square', '4', 'string with space', '-arg']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv` module provides a way to split strings while keeping quoted substrings intact.

```
>>> import csv
>>> s = 'square 4 "string with space" -arg'
>>> next(csv.reader([s], delimiter=' '))
['square', '4', 'string with space', '-arg']
```

This is not proper command line parsing, of course. If you can take the user input upon program invocation, look into the `argparse` module.